# How do I sync my Xbox360 controller without access to the "Sync" button?

Tags: pc, controllers

Long story short, I can't press the **Sync button** on my *controller* while the *[reciever](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/Xbox_360_Wireless_Receiver.png/200px-Xbox_360_Wireless_Receiver.png)* is on *Sync mode* so I can't sync them as I used to.

Anyone has faced this same missfortune before and know how to sync them?

*PS: the **Sync button** is not broken and it works, but I don't have access to it while the controller is on.*

Comment: Are you having troubles with a battery not charging (or no battery at all) and no adaptor for AAA batteries? I don't know how to sync without pressing the button, but I might be able to help you if you tell me why you can't press it.

Comment: I have a **Charge & Play Kit** but the battery only works while connected to the charger. I could always ask for a friend's AAA batteries adaptor but would like to have a solution without deppending on anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: You should be able to connect the play and charge kit directly to the 360 and the cable should sync the controller to that console right away. I went for the 2 workarounds because I was guessing this wasn't working for some reason but I just realized you might not have tried it yet (and trying it with the controler connected to another usb power source).

---

You can bridge 2 AAA batteries with a few copper coins to keep the pressure (pennies will do, or any brown colored coin). Keep in mind the coins will be conducting electricity and as such might give you a very small jolt if touched while the controller is on. Nothing dangerous, similar to what you get if you lick a battery.

[A video of the coin methode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RJkkoMxuMQ)

The alternative, is drilling a hole directly leading to where the button would be, and then use a needle to push the sync button. Using powertools should always be supervised by a grown up, so if you are a minor, just ask your mother or father for help.

Comment: I'm trying to sync it to the **pc** via a **receiver**, not to the Xbox. Anyways, thanks for the ideas [let's do this](http://www.canarias7.es/servicios/i/promo/manny_manitas.gif)

Comment: Have you tried connecting the play and charge kit and receiver to the PC (if running windows) at the same time to see if they sync?

Comment: **Charge & Play** is not able to send data to the computer, that's why I need to use a receiver

Comment: I know, but using both at the same time might work. I'm thinking MS might have covered the sync button for a reason - and that is, the controller will auto-sync to whatever is connected. So, in case of a PC, having both adapter and cable connected at the same time would work. I'm just guessing here, but it wouldn't hurt to try.

Comment: I do already have it like that, both connected to an usb hub on my pc and not syncing

Comment: Have you tried without the hub? Adapter first, controler+charger 2nd.

Comment: Yeah, does not work, the charger just can't transfer any kind of data to the computer, so it's acting like a normal charger but via USB